# Are questions asking how well a piece of hardware does X accepted?

Tags: discussion

So I got an MP3 player (technically MP4, but the screen is about the size of my thumb), but it's old and obviously doesn't support Bluetooth headsets. Reason I wanted a Bluetooth headset was due to my earplugs' connection piece constantly breaking after a couple weeks. Anyway, ...

Answer (score 2):

Generally, no. Questions should ask for a recommendation of specific hardware - that means if you've already got hardware, this is probably not the right site for it.

However, if you haven't bought the hardware yet, but are looking at one option in particular, you *can* turn the question around. Instead of asking "How well does X do Y?", you can ask "I want an A that does Y well, and I'm particularly interested in your opinions on X".